# find the range of the $b$, if $a^2+b^2+c^2=21~~~~2b=a+c$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $\Delta ABC$ such $|AC|=b,|BC|=a,|AB|=c$,and such $$\begin{cases}
2b=a+c\\
a^2+b^2+c^2=21
\end{cases}$$
find the range of the $b$
since
$$(a+c)^2-2ac+b^2=21$$
so we have
$$2ac=5b^2-21$$
then $a,c$ is a  equation
$$x^2-2bx+\dfrac{5b^2-21}{2}=0$$ roots.so we have
$$\Delta =4b^2-2(5b^2-21)=42-6b^2\ge 0\Longrightarrow -\sqrt{7}\le b\le \sqrt{7}$$

**the book  aswer: $\sqrt{6}<b\le\sqrt{7}$**

Comment: To find range, it is not enough to find bounds, you have to show the bounds can be achieved. $a=b=c=\sqrt7$ shows the upper bound is achievable, but clearly side of a triangle is positive, so your lower bound is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lower bound we have: $b > |a-c| \implies b^2 > (a-c)^2, (2b)^2 = (a+c)^2\implies 5b^2 > (a-c)^2 + (a+c)^2 = 2(a^2+c^2) = 2(21- b^2) \implies 7b^2 > 42 \implies b^2 > 6 \implies b > \sqrt{6}$.

Comment: To show this gives the range, one needs to also show we can get arbitrarily close to the degenerate triangle with sides $\sqrt6/2, \sqrt6, 3\sqrt6/2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Upper bound**

Since $a+c=2b$ we have that $a+b+c=3b.$ Now, squaring we get

$$9b^2=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc.$$ Using that $a^2+b^2+c^2=21$ and $ab+ac+bc\le a^2+b^2+c^2=21$ we get $b^2\le 7.$ So, we have that upper bound $b\le \sqrt{7}.$